# Descriptive programming to click the link on web whose title changes dynamically

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to write a script in UFT, where i need to click on a link (Always the first link in the table), whose title changes dynamically. I tries the following :

```
Dim obj_ChkDesc

Set obj_ChkDesc=Description.Create
obj_ChkDesc(“Class Name”).value = “Link”
Obj_ChkDesc("name").value="Log in"

Browser().page().link(obj_ChkDesc).click
```

It doesn't work as when the value changes it fails.
Could someone tell me what needs to be done to click on the first link whose title changes dynamically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally, if the object I want to control is known (i.e. always the first link... seems pretty well defined to me), then I would not use descriptive programming to find it.  I would GuiSpy it, then find something about that link that can always be predicted... perhaps something in the innertext, or something in the URL.. In this case, Index seems to be reliable  ;)  whatever it is, I build an OR object around that so I can simply call the object by name and say .click   ...I only use Descriptive Programming when I don't know WHICH of my OR objects I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

First, use `Regular Expression`. But it has an assumption that the `link` name should follow some rules, say dynamic 10 digits, then you can use `[0-9]{10}` as regular expression pattern. To do it, you need to use `Spy` to capture this link, then change its property like `outerhtml` to regular expression...

Another way (I recommend this one): since you mentioned it is a `WebTable`. There is a method called `ChildItem`. Let's say the link you want to click will always at `Row 1, Col 1`. Then you can write things like this:

```
'Set Table object
Set TableObj = Browser(...).Page(...).WebTable(...)
'Locate Link
Set LinkObj = TableObj.ChildItem(1,1,"Link",0)
LinkObj.Click
```

Note that parameter here `1,1,"Link",0` meaning `Row,Col,ClassName,Index`. `Index` may cause confusion here. Say `Row 1 Col 1` has two links, and you want to click second link, then `Index` should be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, based on your statement: `where i need to click on a link`**`(Always the first link in the table)`**, you don't need to use **`Obj_ChkDesc("name").value`** because in general **`name`** property will be different for each links. And by using it you are specifically looking for that link.
You can simply use:

```
Browser().page().ChildObjects(obj_ChkDesc)(0).Click
```

Another thing, you should also include WebTable in your statement above, otherwise you'll end up covering all the links from the page and NOT just from particular table.